# Why the Couchbase views are accessed using HTTP REST API?

Tags: couchbase

I've started investigating Couchbase 2.0 features, and I know CouchDB exposed only HTTP API, but I'm a bit surprised that Couchbase 2.0 (evolving from 1.8 where you were using memcached exclusively) exposes the views in same matter.

What are the considerations here? Isn't it possible to query the view using memcached?

Answer (score 1):

With Couchbase Server 2.0, it's not possible to query the view using the Memcached API.  However, keep in mind that the view is primarily a secondary index that will be used either to retrieve some projection of the original document or to retrieve the original document from the ID returned by the view query.

In other words, the pattern (Python in this case) would be:

```
view = bucket.view("_design/beer/_view/by_name")
```

Then as you iterate over the view, you'd take the ID from each row and retrieve the original document using the Memcached API.  Again, in Python:

```
for row in view:    
    id = row["id"].__str__()    
    original_doc = bucket.get(id)[2]
```

Comment: I suspected it might be the common pattern, I'm just wondering if the HTTP request won't be the bottleneck here, forcing someone to abandon views in performance-sensitive areas.